# Change privacy setting from application in ios swift 3 and come back on same state of application

Tags: swift

i developed a ios application for to capture photos.
i am trying to access camera for capture photos for that i updated in info.plist  "Privacy - Camera Usage Description".
but when permission dialog box opened i am click on don't allow .

to change camera permission goto setting using

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

but after changing camera permission and click on back the application will be restrated.
how to come on same state on click back from setting

Answer (score 1):

**Its not possible directly** 
Still you want to achieve you have to manage accordingly.

When coming back from settings app, our app restarts again that is `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` called it will start again.

You can use userdefault to store a bool or something and then push to your screen accordingly.

**It Works For me.**

Comment: thanks for this, but when i click on camera toggle button on command prompt this display this message "Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9" and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions not called.

Comment: Yes, it happens some times you need to restart the app by yourself only.Sometime while changing settings iphone itself show the message from debugger.

Comment: how can i handle "Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9"  this one or avoid

Comment: you cannot handle such message the user need to start app again.!